# Where is the gunner glyphmaster?

Tags: tera

I can't find the glyphmaster for gunners in Velika. It doesn't seem to be by the gunner trainer, which is where all the other glyphmasters are. Could someone help me by telling me the location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TERA removed the need for glyphmasters in a previous update, and any glyphmasters you see in the game now are not strictly needed.  If you open your skills window (default keybind is <kbd>k</kbd>), you can instantly equip a glyph by finding the appropriate skill in the list and clicking on the glyph options. This is possible for all glyphs of common rarity.

For the rare glyphs, you can still get them via glyph boxes, other NPCs, or the broker.

Comment: However you still are limited by the amount points gained.

Comment: thank you i just startet again and so i searched for the gunner master xD